# USER DNS through a repeater bridge not loading

Tags: wireless-router, repeater, satellite

I have a two router & modem (satellite) set-up and have issues with DHCP settings and internet DNS connections. My first router is connected via wired lan to my modem, and is connected to the second router via wireless. The second router is running DD-WRT and configured as a repeater bridge. It has DHCP disabled.  My device connected to the repeater bridge will not transmit data smoothly to the device (I-link receiver).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your title says that DNS is not working ("loading"), but the main test says the data is not transmitting smoothly.  Can you be more specific about the symtoms?

Comment: How isn't it transmitting smoothly? Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of latency in satellite downlink, try setting your TCP TTL to a higher value. Ping your DNS server's IP address to check it.